# jQuery accordion is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following jQuery and HTML code for accordion.

The icons are not changing as the panels are collapsed/shown.
On click of the panel header, the panel should become visible and collapse.

I have also used Bootstrap `glyphicon`.

```js
 var selectIds =$('#collapse1,#collapse2,#collapse3');
        $(function ($) {
        selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).prev().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Panel 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Contents panel 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Contents panel 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: see this for complete reference
https://codepen.io/vikasverma93/pen/raxGaM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDs and classes don't match.

- Replace `#collapse` with `#panel`
- Replace `fa` with `glyphicon`

**See the working demo below:**

```js
var selectIds =$('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3');
$(function ($) {
    selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse  hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Panel 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Contents panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```